# Cplex OPL:eliminate some dvar in preprocessing

Tags: cplex, preprocessor, opl

I have  a question regarding eliminating some invalid decision variable commbinations in the preprocessing.
I have a 2-dimensional decision variable X indexed with [commodities][arcs].Please see the code below.The index "commodities" is based on the tuple "Data".The index "arcs" is based on the tuple "Arc".Both tuples "Data" and "Arc" are based on a tuple "TimeNode".
I dont'want the program iterate all X combinations. I want to remove some of the decision variables in the preprocessing, by considering a condition where I compare  Origin time in the Data tuple and FromNode time in the Arc tuple and if "Origin.time>FromNode.time", X equals 0,thus eliminated from iteration and not regarded. Thus, the size of the problem will be reduced and some memory saved. I made some examplary code below, with execute. If i have, for example, {Data} commodities= {<1 <1 3><2 8>>...}, 1 is an id, <1 3> - Origin with 1 as a starting node and 3 is a start time. I do not need the problem to regard all Xs earlier than start time 3.
However, the execute does not work as X is a decision variable. What could I possibly do? Formulate the condition as a constraint? Thank you. I would appriciate any advice.

```
  tuple TimeNode { 
  int node;
  int time;}
  {TimeNode} tnodes = { <n,t> | n in Nodes, t in Time };

  tuple Data{            
  int id;
  TimeNode Origin;           
  TimeNode Destination; }
  {Data} commodities= {<1 <1 3><2 8>>, <2 <2 5><3 10>>};

  tuple Arc {  
  TimeNode FromNode      
  TimeNode ToNode; }
  {Arc} arcs={<<i,s>,<j,e>> | <i,j> in st_arcs, s in Time , e in Time };

  dvar float+ x[commodities][arcs];

  execute {
       for(var c in commodities){
         for(var a in arcs){
           if(c.Origin.time>a.FromNode.time)
            x[c][a]=0;
         }
       }
  }
```

"ERROR:Assignment to decision variable in "x # 0 # 0" not possible."

Answer (score 1):

you could write that in the subject to block:

```
subject to
  {
    forall( c in commodities, a in arcs:c.Origin.time>a.FromNode.time) x[c][a]==0;
  }
```

For instance

```
{int} s={1,2};

dvar int x[s] in 0..10;

maximize sum(i in s) x[i];
subject to
{
  forall(i in s:i<=1) x[i]==0;
}
```

works fine

and is better than

```
{int} s={1,2};

dvar int x[s] in 0..10;

execute
{
  for(var i in s) if (i<=1) x[i].UB=0;
}

maximize sum(i in s) x[i];
subject to
{
  //forall(i in s:i<=1) x[i]==0;
}
```

that looks like what you tried to write

But what is the best is often to build a new set and then to have decision variables for the meaningful subset:

```
{int} s={1,2};
{int} s2={i | i in s :i>1};

dvar int x[s2] in 0..10;



maximize sum(i in s2) x[i];
subject to
{
  
}
```

Comment: Definitely agree with Alex that the best approach is to only create the variables that you actually need in your model. There are a few special cases where it can be useful to have these extra variables in the model (e.g. for debugging), but generally better not to create them. Put the effort into getting your index sets correct and it will pay big dividends both in your understanding of your model and in reduced model size and (usually) better solve times.

Comment: Sometimes, however, you need to for example solve the linear programming relaxation in order to figure out which variables should be eliminated. And there, it could be nice with a "remove variable from model" function, instead of relying on the preprocessing to eliminate variables with equal lower and upper bounds.